# .txt to binary c++, issue with int

Tags: text, binary, int

I have a text file that I am converting to binary. Its a 7 digit no. followed by a name and then repeat for however many names is listed.

```
1234567 First Last
7654321 First Last
```

Because its a 7 digit int, I am having trouble outputting it to the binary using this method with the int struct. It gives me an awfully large .DAT (binary) file whenever I write to it even with say just 3 names. Is there a better way of outputting it so my binary .dat files look about 200kb and doesn't end up in the 20mb+ range?

```
const int MAX = 50;

struct StudentRegistration{
    int studentID;
    char name[MAX];
};

    fstream afile;
    ifstream infile;

  afile.open (fileName2, ios::out | ios::binary);
    infile.open (fileName1);

 while (infile >> s.studentID)
    {
        infile.get(space);
        infile.getline(&s.name, MAX);
        afile.seekp((s.studentID-1)*sizeof(StudentRegistration), ios::beg);
        afile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&s), sizeof(s));
    }

    afile.close();
    infile.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the seekp line and it seems to do what I want to it for now.

Comment: For clarification why that happens, your seekp line seeks further into the file and then writes data.  If your filesystem doesn't support sparse files, that seeking will cause the file to consume the space you seeked over, even though you didn't actually write any data there.